# Setting C-p as helm-projectile-find-file

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, evil, helm-projectile

I put this at the very end of my config file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") 'helm-projectile-find-file)
```

On Emacs start I can see that it is getting assigned using `C-h k C-p`. Then when I actually load a project, it gets overwritten and becomes `evil-paste-pop`

How can I make this to stay set as `helm-projectile-find-file`?

Comment: Not directly related to the question but the op may not be aware of helm-projectile-on, which may obviate the need to create a custom key binding.

Comment: Please clarify how `helm-projectile-on` helps: explain for example how&when to use it and in which sense it makes a keybinding unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that minor modes, in this case Evil, take precedence over the global keymap. One solution is to add the binding directly to `evil-normal-state-map`, as in

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-p") 'helm-projectile)
```

You can do the same for the insert/visual/etc maps if you'd like.

Alternatively, you can use the `bind-key*` macro from the `bind-key` package (should already be installed if you use `use-package`, Spacemacs, DOOM Emacs, etc.). The asterisk signifies that your binding will not be placed in the global keymap, but instead added to the keymap for `bind-key`'s own `override-global-mode` (which lives inside `emulation-mode-map-alists`, whose members take precedence over those in `minor-mode-map-alist`... sneaky!). Usage is simple:

```
(bind-key* "C-p" 'helm-projectile)
```

Finally, you can use the great Swiss Army Knife of keybinding tools, [general.el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#override-keymaps-and-buffer-local-keybindings). Something like:

```
(general-define-key
 :states '(normal insert)
 :keymaps 'override
 "C-p" 'helm-projectile)
```

This being Emacs, I'm sure there are a million other solutions.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see your message. Now I made another attempt to use emacs and I run into the same issue. 
I googled the problem and found this page and then saw your post. 
This totally works, so thank you very much for this!